# Integer difference in python between two dates

Tags: python, date, datetime

I've RTFM and read many questions and answers here on SO regarding this, and was happily using strftime and strptime yesterday, so I would swear this should work, but it isn't....

I just want an integer.  Not a "timedelta object."  Not an "aware yet hashable object" (see, I RTFM).   Not a tuple.  Not a dictionary.   Just a simple freaking integer so I can use an if statement and branch and be happy.  Please bring the light of your wisdom upon this, with thanks.

Here's what I have

```
...
import datetime
mdate = "2010-10-05"
rdate = "2010-10-05"
mdate1 = datetime.strptime(mdate, "%Y-%m-%d")
rdate1 = datetime.strptime(rdate, "%Y-%m-%d")
delta =  datetime.timedelta.days(mdate1 - rdate1)
```

Here's what I get:

```
pmain.py:4: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'strptime'
(error hits in the 'mdate1..." line above)
```

And, that doesn't mean that my delta line is going to work -- please look at that one, too.

Comment: `datetime.datetime.strptime`

Comment: Partial credit.  Next error hits for delta line:  pmain.py:6: TypeError: 'member_descriptor' object is not callable

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You want to get the *classmethod* `datetime.datetime.strptime()`, then take the `.days` **attribute** from the resulting timedelta:

```
import datetime

mdate = "2010-10-05"
rdate = "2010-10-05"
mdate1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(mdate, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
rdate1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(rdate, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
delta =  (mdate1 - rdate1).days
```

So you have the `datetime` module, which has a `datetime.datetime` class, which in turn has a `datetime.datetime.strptime()` method on it. I also added calls to `.date()` to extract *just* the date portion (result is a `datetime.date` instance); this makes dealing with timestamps that differ slightly less than a multiple of 24 hours easier.

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> mdate = "2010-10-05"
>>> rdate = "2010-10-05"
>>> mdate1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(mdate, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
>>> rdate1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(rdate, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
>>> delta =  (mdate1 - rdate1).days
>>> print delta
0
>>> type(delta)
<type 'int'>
```

Comment: Perfet, Martijn - and as always you answer and explain and benefit future coders with your answers.  Happy happy code now -- many thanks!

Comment: Might be better to also check seconds in case the OP wants to round to the nearest whole day.

Comment: Is the type of the variable `delta` an `int`?

Comment: @George: added verification that it is indeed an `int`, just for you.

Comment: @Aya: No, this *is* whole days already. That is what the `.days()` calls are for.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oops. Forgot the `strptime` was only on a date, although there are some [unusual cases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result) where you might not get back a `timedelta` where `seconds` is zero.

Comment: @Aya: Yup, but not here, because the default `datetime` objects are timezone-naive (no timezone info at all, so no DST and no timezone changes either). :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Okay. You win this round. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

```
sign1['days'] = sign1['diff'] / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
```

I had the same problem and it solved by uding the above statement.
I hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
import datetime
mdate = "2010-11-05"
rdate = "2010-10-05"
mdate1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(mdate, "%Y-%m-%d")
rdate1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(rdate, "%Y-%m-%d")
delta = (mdate1 - rdate1).days
```